# How to determine which device is not registered

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to determine which particular device is "NotRegisterd".

I send message to some butch of devices. Here my body:

```
{
   "registration_ids": ["someCode1", "someCode2", "someCode3"],
   "notification": {...},
   "data": {...}
}
```

And got response:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 6613705169343972705,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 2,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    },
    {
      "message_id": "0:1496749257460993%5fe3e4105fe3e410"
    },
    {
      "error": "NotRegistered"
    }]
}
```

How to determine which devices not registered?
I have only one idea. The order of registration_ids is equal order of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Table 5 of the [HTTP Server Protocol documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) it describes the results array as:

> Array of objects representing the status of the messages processed.
> The objects are listed in the same order as the request (i.e., for
> each registration ID in the request, its result is listed in the same
> index in the response)

So your guess is correct, the order of the results is the same order as the registration IDs.